# Shopify (.liquid) and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, shopify

For a bit of context, we are interested in building out this feature here. The example in STEP 1 is exactly what we want our website to have:

http://recharge.helpscoutdocs.com/article/96-combining-different-pre-pai-intervals-onto-one-product

However, we're having trouble integrating it and figuring out what STEP 2 is actually telling us and were hoping you guys would be open to helping us out. We are using Shopify and integrating it with a 3rd party app for our subscription model called ReCharge.

We're looking at having the following choices for our products:

4 weeks - $55
6 weeks - $60
8 weeks - $65

Thank you very much. If you guys need more context, let me know.

Benny

Answer (score 0):

Step 2 is changing the values on "two hidden input" fields using JS. In the form these two fields are not displayed and a proxy selection option is in place.

So using JS, those input values are changed based on the proxy selection.